# Core Data NSPredicate for date

Tags: date, core-data, nspredicate

In my model I have date attribute and I set it `[NSDate date]`, but getting with predicate like

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"date==%@ ,date];
```

returns notting. I know the problem is when I set  `[NSDate date]` it stores also time and NSPredicate always return empty data. Is there any way to convert `"date==%@"` part to only look for date?

Comment: The problem with doing predicates with dates like this is that this will be doing a sub-millisecond comparison; you must have *exactly* the same instant in time, not just the same calendar day.

Comment: This "you must have exactly the same instant in time" made me think of this idea to deal with time in dates: make the time of your date all 0s right before storing it. And when retrieving from model pass a date value with time as 0s.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];
```

Comment: thanks for response , but I have one date (today). endDate should be tomorrow?

Comment: its ur choice.. don't give end date, remove tat part. pass only startDate.


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@)", startDate];

Comment: setting only startDate caused that if I give 2 days before date it returns me all records between 2 days before and today. I fixed it adding 1 day to selected date and used your first response with endDate.

Comment: Are the brackets really necessary?